# R² of 1 with dynlm procedure?

Tags: r, lags

Dear statisticians/programmers,

I want to model the price of AXE deoderands in Albert Heijn (a dutch supermarket) as a linear function of its own past (up to two lags) and the past of the price of AXE deoderants in jumbo (another dutch supermarket), to check whether the price in Jumbo granger causes the price Albert Heijn.

Anyway, I try to model this by means of the dynlm procedure in R. This however, gives an R² of 1 and the effect of the first lag is equal to 1. So something is wrong with the code but I cannot find out what.

Can somebody please help me with this issue? The code and output are below. Many thanks in advance!

```
Fit_grang_AH <- dynlm(albert$AXEPrice~lag(albert$AXEPrice, k=-1)+lag(albert$AXEPrice, k=-2)+lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k=-1)+lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k=-2))

dynlm(formula = albert$AXEPrice ~ L(albert$AXEPrice, k = -1) + 
lag(albert$AXEPrice, k = -2) + lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k = -1) + 
lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k = -2))

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-2.749e-15 -4.370e-18  1.814e-17  2.764e-17  3.943e-16 

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                              Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  2.552e-15  2.347e-16 1.087e+01   <2e-16 ***
lag(albert$AXEPrice, k = -1)   1.000e+00  7.992e-17 1.251e+16   <2e-16 ***
lag(albert$AXEPrice, k = -2)        NA         NA        NA       NA    
lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k = -1)  2.008e-17  1.139e-16 1.760e-01     0.86    
lag(jumbo$AXEPrice, k = -2)         NA         NA        NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.568e-16 on 121 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.477e+32 on 2 and 121 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: This kind of things happen when your model is heavily overfitting, `NA`'s in your output could also suggest that. Have you checked for overfitting?

Comment: When I use only the first lag for Price in Albert Heijn I also get an R² of 1. I do not think it is due to overfitting.

Comment: Please post the reproducible example. One possible problem is your use of `$` in formula. The standard R way is the following: `dynlm(y~l(x,-1),data=dt)`, where `x` and `y` are the columns in a data.frame dt. In your case you are referencing two data sources: `albert` and `jumbo`. I suspect they have different structures, so R fails to merge them properly. These are only guesses, if you have posted the data, such type of questions could be answered precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use `dynlm` library with [some data](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html):

```
kings <- scan("http://robjhyndman.com/tsdldata/misc/kings.dat",skip=3)
summary(dynlm(kings ~ L(kings, 1)))
```

it also gives $R^2$ of 1.

**EDIT:** As mpiktas pointed in a discussion below, it seems to be a bug in dynlm library: it works fine if predictor variable is provides ad `ts` object:

```
summary(dynlm(kings ~ L(ts(kings), 1)))
```

or when `dynlm` is used with `dplyr` library loaded:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dynlm)
summary(dynlm(kings ~ L(kings, 1)))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I do not get the $R^2=1$ with your code. What R and dynlm version are you using?

Comment: R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)

Comment: Works correctly on R 3.1.1 and dynlm version 0.3-3.

Comment: I updated R to version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) - this is not my PC for analysis - and dynlm to 0.3-3 and on my machine $R^2 = 1$. So it could be some kind of strange bug...

Comment: Apparently dynlm does not like non-ts objects. If you do `kings<-ts(kings)` then it proceeds as normal. If the data does not have time series structure, the `L` function does not work. Strangely enough if library `dplyr` is loaded after `dynlm`, the `L` function starts to work as expected. This is why I was not able to reproduce the bug in the first place.

Comment: Ok no strangeness. The `lag` function behaviour is one of annoying things about R. By default it does not shift the vector, but only changes the attributes. So `lag(1:10, k=-1)` results in the same vector `1:10`, with attribute `tsp`. Package **dplyr** overrides the default lag function and `lag(1:10,k=-1)` results in `c(NA,1:9)`. Since nowadays `dplyr` is almost always loaded in my R sessions, I did not get the bug the first time.

Comment: Yes, but this *is* a bug in `dynlm` because it causes it to provide biased results.

Comment: It is a bug now, because the help does not say that dynlm explicitly requires time series objects. Otherwise it would not be a bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19077/discussion-between-tim-and-mpiktas).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to mpiktas for explaining most of the problem. Just a few short additions:

The function `L()` inside `dynlm()` is just a shortcut that internally calls `lag()` so that `L(x, 1:2)` is the same as `lag(x, -1) + lag(x, -2)`. Therefore, when `lag()` works as desired then `L()` also works as desired. This may be the case if either `x` is a time series object (`"ts"` or `"zoo"`) or when additional packages like `dplyr` or others are loaded which provide additional `lag()` methods.

The package `dynlm` itself recommends to provide time series data objects. The main manual page `?dynlm` says in the details section (note the last sentence that I have highlighted here):

For specifying the formula of the model to be fitted, there are additional functions available which allow for convenient specification of dynamics (via `d()` and `L()`) or linear/cyclical patterns (via `trend()`, `season()`, and `harmon()`). *All new formula functions require that their arguments are time series objects (i.e., `"ts"` or `"zoo"`).*